# Animate does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Please have a look at http://ipll.manoa.hawaii.edu/ind/tiw/lessons/L22/index.htm

If you search for "kata baru" and then click on the link it opens the file daftar_kata.htm in a sidebar. This works great in Safari and Firefox, but the content of the file is not displayed in Chrome. I have copied the code here, but it seems that the problem is caused by the css code in file daftarkata.css. When I rename daftarkata.css Chrome does display the content (but not the formatting of course). Therefore I have also copied the css code.

Many thanks!!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {
$("#sidebar2inner").load("daftar_kata.htm table");
});
});
$(function() {
    
    var $sidebar = $('#sidebar2'), $splitter = $('[id^=splitter]'), $close = $('.close');
    $('#sidebar2').hide();
    $splitter.toggle(
        function() { 
            $sidebar.animate({ width: 'show' }, 400);
            $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 'slow');
        },
        function() {
            $sidebar.animate({ width: 'hide' }, 400);
            $('#page').animate({margin: '0 auto'}, 'slow');
        }
    );
        
     
    $splitter.height( $('#main').height() );
    
    $close.click(function(){
            $sidebar.animate({ width: 'hide' }, 400);
            $('#page').animate({margin: '0 auto'}, 'slow');
    });
    
    var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36];
    jQuery.each(arr, function(index, item) {
        $('#transkrip' + item + 'Container').hide();
    });
    jQuery.each(arr, function(index, item) {
      $('#transkrip' + item).toggle(
       function() {
        $('#transkrip'+item+'Container').animate({height:'show'},400);
       },
       function(){
        $('#transkrip'+item+'Container').animate({height:'hide'},400);
       }
      );
    });

});
</script>
```

CSS CODE

```css
.daftarkata {

 margin:0px;padding:0px;

 width:100%;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;

 border:1px solid #b2b2b2;

 

 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:14px;

 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:14px;

 border-bottom-left-radius:14px;

 

 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:14px;

 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:14px;

 border-bottom-right-radius:14px;

 

 -moz-border-radius-topright:14px;

 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:14px;

 border-top-right-radius:14px;

 

 -moz-border-radius-topleft:14px;

 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:14px;

 border-top-left-radius:14px;

}table.daftarkata{

 width:100%;

 height:100%;

 margin:0px;padding:0px;

}table.daftarkata tr:last-child td:last-child {

 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:14px;

 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:14px;

 border-bottom-right-radius:14px;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child td:first-child {

 -moz-border-radius-topleft:14px;

 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:14px;

 border-top-left-radius:14px;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child td:last-child {

 -moz-border-radius-topright:14px;

 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:14px;

 border-top-right-radius:14px;

}table.daftarkata tr:last-child td:first-child{

 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:14px;

 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:14px;

 border-bottom-left-radius:14px;

}table.daftarkata tr:hover td{

 background-color:#e5e5e5;

  


}

table.daftarkata td{

 vertical-align:top;

 

 background-color:#ffffff;


 border:1px solid #b2b2b2;

 border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;

 text-align:left;

 padding:7px;

 font-size:10px;

 font-family:Verdana;

 font-weight:normal;

 color:#000000;

}table.daftarkata tr:last-child td{

 border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;

}table.daftarkata tr td:last-child{

 border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;

}table.daftarkata tr:last-child td:last-child{

 border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child td{

  background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 5%, #e5e5e5 100%); background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e5e5e5) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e5e5e5 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#e5e5e5"); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff,e5e5e5);


 background-color:#ffffff;

 border:0px solid #b2b2b2;

 text-align:center;

 border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;

 font-size:17px;

 font-family:Verdana;

 font-weight:bold;

 color:#33aacc;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child:hover td{

 background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 5%, #e5e5e5 100%); background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e5e5e5) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e5e5e5 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#e5e5e5"); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff,e5e5e5);


 background-color:#ffffff;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child td:first-child{

 border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;

}

table.daftarkata tr:first-child td:last-child{

 border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;

}
```

Comment: When I click on `kata baru` it shows Lesson 22 in the sidebar. Is that wrong?

Comment: Your site link opened fine here, Chrome on Mac OS X

Comment: did you fix it? it shows fine to me on my windows 7 Chrome. Also very cool to see Indonesian lesson! I am indonesian :)

Comment: Hi, after I had this problem for months on my Macbook Pro, I tried on several other computers, and it worked! I then reinstalled Chrome and run all updates, and now it works! So sorry for having bothered you. Makasih banyak, Melissa.